# Inkscape .91 with latex

Tags: math, latex, formula, inkscape

I am using Inkscape 0.91 and trying to add Latex math formula inside my graphics. After several hours of tying and fixes from the I am still not able make it work. I am on Windows 7 with the following,

1) pstoedit (pstoeditsetup_win32.exe)

2) GSview 5.0 (gsv50w32.exe)

3) Ghostscript 9.18 (gs918w32.exe)

4) miktex 2.59 64 bit version

I have added the PATHs and did all the stuff. I can see the Latex extension as well but whenever I try to use it I face the following error:

"Problem during opening C:\Program Files (x86)\pstoedit\drvmagick.dll:The specified module could not be found."

I couldn't find any solution to this so far.

Comment: some 32bit apps have troubles with `(x86)` program files path ... try to copy the content of the pstoedit to 64bit program files folder as well (or viceversa) that usually helps ...

Comment: i did it but it didnt work. it still  keeps saying that specific dll is not found.

Comment: if it uses any form of driver and that dll is just hooking up to it then you are in trouble As WoW64 has different driver access then the raw 32bit environment. There are workarounds but you need to find out if this is just file path related or driver related ...

Comment: okay funny enough, its working right now, creating the math formulas in latex and putting them on to the page, however it is still giving the same error...

Comment: I have the same effect as previous comment - saying cannot find the module and then working. However my GhostView, Pstoedit and Inkscape are all in Program Files (64bit) and I have not installed GSview at all

Comment: have you tried using https://pav.iki.fi/software/textext/ instead?

Comment: @Foad yes I tried using that addon as well previously but I never managed to make it work.

Comment: It does work, though with some minor issues. try this page: https://bitbucket.org/pitgarbe/textext

Answer (score 1):

So basically you are seeing this error while trying to use laTeX to add a formula or text to your drawing. as explained in [this page](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/LaTeX) you go to Extensions->Render->LaTeX. but the same error happened on windows 10 and Inkscape 0.92:

[image]

Doing some search I found [this post in Inkscape forums](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=4937). There several possible soloutions have been proposed, but the one which worked for me was to delete the faulty file:

> drvmagick.dll

and it now works just fine.