# Inkscape and latex extension

Tags: latex, inkscape

I am using Windows 10 and inkscape. I want to use the Latex extension in Inkscape and have found several instructions to download GS, ghostview, pstoedit, miktex and so forth. Then add these to PATH.

For example here: [Inkscape and Latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341689/inkscape-91-with-latex)

However, I have not found any instructions for Win 10. When I do as instructed, I do not see any option in Inkscape Extension-Render

Has anyone gotten this to work on Windows 10?

Or are there other good vector graphic programs that are good and has Latex extension?
/ Erik

Answer (score 1):

For me it turned out to be a problem of getting textext to work with a newer inkscape version. Most instructions that I found where for textext to work with an inkscape version < 0.48. I got everything to work with inkscape 0.92.1 when I followed the instructions [here](https://bitbucket.org/pitgarbe/textext/src). Though you ask this question a while ago, I hope it still helps (if not for you then at least maybe for others).

Comment: Ah, yeah, that guy totally fixed the plugin.  Thanks for the link!!

Comment: The link is not working now. Perhaps the content was moved elsewhere?